# How to set ID attribute to svg elements according to displaying order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, fabricjs

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1069" height="575" xml:space="preserve">
    <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.4.13</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <rect x="-20" y="-20" rx="10" ry="10" width="40" height="40" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.3; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: DarkSalmon; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"
    transform="translate(461.15 451.15)" id="0"></rect>
    <rect x="-20" y="-20" rx="10" ry="10" width="40" height="40" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.3; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: DarkSalmon; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(429.15 310.15)"
    id="1"></rect>
    <rect x="-20" y="-20" rx="10" ry="10" width="40" height="40" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.3; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: DarkSalmon; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(351.15 177.15)"
    id="2"></rect>
```

this code has generated by fabricjs.1st added rect object is placed in first line in svg code.before genarate the svg code i change the positions of rect object by dragging.but the svg code has not changed acording to that.what i want to do is set the ID to every rect in svg code acording to displaying order.displaying order means top to bottom or bottom to top on screen.is it possible to do?thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this JS to give each 'rect' tag an id based on its location.

```
var SVG = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var children = SVG.childNodes;
var ID = 0;
[].forEach.call(children, function (child) {
    if(child.nodeType === 1 && child.tagName == "rect"){
        child.setAttribute('id', ID);
        ID++;
    }
});
```

This will give the id 0 to the first 'rect' 1 to the next and so on.

Comment: This code set IDs according to SVG code.suppose, in SVG code 1st element is red color rectangle.but when displaying this SVG code that red rectangle placed on bottom of the screen.that is the transformation of element.when i starting count on top of the screen  it is last rectangle.what i want to do is, set the IDs according to screen coordinates.how can do that?any example or idea would be appreciated.